# Which basic operations are undefined even for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm aware of:

- $\frac{X}{0}$ (dividing by zero)
- $0^0$ (raising zero to the power of zero)

Are there any others?

Comment: $z^w$ is a little weird but that's the closest thing I have that you didn't list.

Comment: @Cameron Williams: What is $z^w$?

Comment: Exponentiating a complex number by another complex number. We define $z^w$ to be $e^{w\log z}$.

Comment: @Cameron Williams: I'm pretty sure that it's actually well defined.

Comment: I didn't say it isn't well defined. I just said it's weird.

Comment: it does go wrong though, i.e what is $2^i$??

Comment: The problem with exponentiation is that $\log(z)$ only defined up to a multiple of $2 i \pi$. So $z^w$ is also multivalued for generic $z$ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

There's always $\infty-\infty$ which tends to go wrong, since you do not know which is the "larger" infinity.

Or you could consider $\infty \times i$ and $\infty i- \infty i$. (keeping it complex)

Comment: $\infty$ is not a complex number

Comment: it is if you consider it as $\infty + 0i$, but in all seriousness, I thought you were looking for other operations that did not work.

Comment: Thanks @ellya. I guess that factorial (if that can be regarded as a *basic operation*) is not defined for certain values, though I'm not even sure how it is defined for complex numbers to begin with.

Comment: @barakmanos The factorial is generalized to all complex numbers (except the nonpositive integers) via the Gamma function.

Comment: @Cameron Williams: I'm aware of what you said, but for **Real numbers**  (for negative integers BTW, not non-positive integers). I'm not sure how it works for **Complex numbers** (i.e., what is a negative complex integer?).

Comment: just to say, you cant really have a negative complex number, as the set of complex numbers lacks ordering, i.e you cant say $a+bi\lt c+di$, so you also can't say $a+bi\lt 0$ which is a formal definition of negative in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @barakmanos The notation for the Gamma function is that $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ when $n$ is a nonnegative integer, not $\Gamma(n) = n!$. It's not the best notational definition in the world and plenty of mathematicians don't like it but we're stuck with it. The Gamma function can be extended to every complex number except $\{\ldots, -3,-2,-1,0\}$.